# PreAuthorize annotation of Symfony2 JMSSecurityExtraBundle not working

Tags: php, symfony

Using the JMSSecurityExtraBundle of Symfony2 I try to create my own expression method and bind it in a controller using the PreAuthorize annotation.

I don't know why but the method is never fired, and the security bundle while trying to evaluate the PreAuthorize annotation concludes with a "Token does not have the required roles.". Seems like is trying to validate roles and not to resolve the PreAuthorize expression.

Example about what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\HelperBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

/** @DI\Service */
class RequestAccessEvaluator
{
    private $container;

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({
     *     "container" = @DI\Inject("service_container"),
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /** @DI\SecurityFunction("isAllowed") */
    public function isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
   /**
     * 
     * @PreAuthorize("isAllowed()")
     * @Route("/bla/{id}")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     * @return json
     */
    public function postBlaAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
```

Comment: Included use `use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\PreAuthorize;` on top of your controller and _cleared your cache_?

Comment: That's not the problem, my controller already has the use statement for PreAuthorize and I cleared the cache several times.

Comment: Have you made sure that you registered the `HelperBundle` in the `jms_di_extra` configuration? http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/configuration#configuration-locations

Comment: Yes I did also that and nothing. Seems that the bundle denies the access before evaluating the method. Debugging a little I found that the bundle evaluates the PreAuthorize annotation exactly in the same way as the  Secure annotation (same methods) and that can not be good. I'm missing something and I don't get it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved my problem... actually I missed that [config](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/configuration).

It worked just putting that in my config.yml and setting the option "expressions" to true.